# How to end a method that has a data type in Java?

Tags: methods, return

I have a method that has `int` data type and I want to end it when a variable `opt==1`. If I use:

```
if(opt==1)
return;
```

it gives an error saying- "incompatible types : missing return value".

The `return` keyword should break out of the method, but it doesn't. Is there any alternative solution to this ?

Comment: Why does your method have the `int` return type? Are you trying to get a number out of it? What is your method?

Comment: Yes, it gives a number. Here is a better look at the program I am making. A separate "main" method runs a "for" loop and at each iteration, the value of loop control variable is given to this method and it checks if this given number is prime or not, through some set of statements. If "opt==1", then the number isn't prime and hence, I don't want this method to return something, rather it would test the next value of the loop control variable. It should only return if the number is prime or "opt==0".

Comment: Then you probably want a `boolean` method, that returns `true` if the given number is prime or `opt==0`. Something like
`if(opt==1) return false;`

Comment: You don't have a choice of not returning anything at all. The function **must** return an `int`, because you've declared it as returning `int`. In the future, do not add relevant details in the comments; instead, [edit] your question and add them there, where they can be seen as part of the question. Also see [mre], which would make it easier to see what you're trying to do and what you're asking, rather than just posting a couple of lines of code totally out of context.

Comment: @Scrapper142 this actually won't work. I also need to print the value each time a it is returned.

Comment: @Ken White so is there any other way of doing this ? Sorry for inconvenience. I will surely do that in future. I am actually new to StackExchange, so I am slowly getting used to the things here.